# Sum & Average: Latex formatting

Tags: summation

I want to describe the following scenario mathematically. I *think* I have it right... Just wanna check!

Lets say we take a reading A. We then take a number of readings (R) (n readings). We then calculate the difference between each reading & A. We then average out these differences & this becomes our result (R).

So, here's what I have:
$$
R = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \overline{(A-R_1 ... A-R_n)}
$$

Answer (score 0):

The average difference is $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (A-R_n)$ which is equal to $A-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n R_n$ which is equivalent to $A-\overline{R}$, where for clarity you might want to define $\overline{R}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n R_n$.

Is that the answer you're looking for?